# Occasional crashes while read from NSDataAsset

Tags: ios, swift, crash, nsdata, memory-alignment

Some of my users reported a crash. I'm not sure if I do the right think, so I show the code and the part of the crash report with the error description and maybe someone has a helpful hint for me.

UseCase: A file in the Asset Catalog contains the coordinates of several border lines of countries. There are also some strings in it. This code fragment reads the file and stores the converted data into variables.

SOMETIMES the app crashes (I receive 1 or 2 reports a week) at the last line of the code fragment (let numberOfCountries = Int(dataReadBufferUInt64)). I have a group of beta testers and they have no problem at all. So it is a frustrating issue.

I think it has something to do HOW I read the data out of the file. Maybe I have to use another way?

Any help/comment is welcomed!

DataStructure:

The Asset is a programmatically produced file. The code fragment is dealing with the header of this file.

First element is a copyright string with some informations of the version of the file, creation date etc.

The string has two elements:
1) the length of the string as a UInt16 value (range 0 ... UInt16.max)
2) the string elements (if length > 0), each "character" as one UInt16 value

Second element is the number of the countries in that file. It is a UInt64 value.

The rest of the data structure is quite complex, but is not relevant here, as the file is read sequential and IF it crashes, it crashes when reading / converting the UInt64.

There is only one version of the file "out in the wild". Every app reads this file every time the UserInterface gets build up. This is why I do not understand the OCCASIONAL crashes ...

The code fragment:

```
// calculate the size of a record, we use "size" as this is the number of bytes used to store on record
// other possibilities:
// .stride = number of bytes used to store one record and the added nul bytes to align to next memory bounds
// .alignment = number of bytes of alignment bounds
let sizeUInt16 : UInt64 =               UInt64(MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size)
let sizeUInt64 : UInt64 =               UInt64(MemoryLayout<UInt64>.size)



// get the data out of the asset catalog
if let countryBorderLineData = NSDataAsset(name: "CountryBorderLine data", bundle: Bundle.main)?.data {

    // the read buffers, one for each expected data type
    var dataReadBufferUInt16 : UInt16 = 0
    var dataReadBufferUInt64 : UInt64 = 0


    // read the string with the entry comment
    // read the length of the string
    (countryBorderLineData as NSData).getBytes(&dataReadBufferUInt16, range: NSRange(location: nextLocation,
                                                                      length: Int(sizeUInt16) ))
    // advance the pointer
    nextLocation += Int(sizeUInt16)

    // take the number of items we should read
    var numberOfItemsToRead : Int = Int(dataReadBufferUInt16)

    // check if this is not an empty string
    if numberOfItemsToRead > 0 {

       // target buffer of the string
       var UTF16Array : [UInt16] = []

       // loop to read all content
       for _ in 0 ..< numberOfItemsToRead {

            // read next string element
            (countryBorderLineData as NSData).getBytes(&dataReadBufferUInt16, range: NSRange(location: nextLocation,
                                                                              length: Int(sizeUInt16) ))
            // advance the pointer
            nextLocation += Int(sizeUInt16)

            // append read string element to the array

            UTF16Array.append(dataReadBufferUInt16)
        }

        // convert the read array into a string
        let resultString = String(utf16CodeUnits: UTF16Array, count: UTF16Array.count)

    }

    // read the number of countries
    (countryBorderLineData as NSData).getBytes(&dataReadBufferUInt64, range: NSRange(location: nextLocation,
                                                                                 length: Int(sizeUInt64) ))
    // advance the pointer
    nextLocation += Int(sizeUInt64)

    // This line SOMETIMES crashes (see crash subset of crash report)
    let numberOfCountries = Int(dataReadBufferUInt64)

    ...

}
```

This part of the crash report shows the error

```
Date/Time:           2019-08-28 22:00:06.5042 +0200
Launch Time:         2019-08-28 22:00:02.2638 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.4 (16G77)
Baseband Version:    1.06.02
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x8000000000000010
VM Region Info: 0x8000000000000010 is not in any region.  Bytes after     previous region: 9223372025580486673  
  REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
  MALLOC_NANO            0000000280000000-00000002a0000000 [512.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--->  
  UNUSED SPACE AT END

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [22974]
Triggered by Thread:  3
```

All methods of this class are called within the following GCD queue:

```
let myQueueForBorderLines : DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(
label: "appName.myQueueForBorderLines", qos: .userInitiated)
```

The used data structures etc. are only read and managed by this class methods, so I think this is not a multithreading issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

With knowing that `numberOfBytesToRead` in the old code cannot be the cause of the issue, I can just show you the recommended usage of `Data` as for now.

```
let sizeUInt16 = MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size
let sizeUInt64 = MemoryLayout<UInt64>.size

// get the data out of the asset catalog
if let countryBorderLineData = NSDataAsset(name: "CountryBorderLine data", bundle: Bundle.main)?.data {
    var nextLocation = 0

    // the read buffers, one for each expected data type
    var dataReadBufferUInt16: UInt16 = 0
    var dataReadBufferUInt64: UInt64 = 0

    // read the string with the entry comment
    // read the length of the string
    _ = withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &dataReadBufferUInt16) {bufPtr in
        countryBorderLineData.copyBytes(to: bufPtr, from: nextLocation...)
    }
    // advance the pointer
    nextLocation += Int(sizeUInt16)

    // take the number of items we should read
    let numberOfItemsToRead = Int(dataReadBufferUInt16)

    // check if this is not an empty string
    if numberOfItemsToRead > 0 {

        // target buffer of the string
        var utf16Array: [UInt16] = Array(repeating: 0, count: numberOfItemsToRead)

        utf16Array.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {bufPtr in
            countryBorderLineData.copyBytes(to: bufPtr, from: nextLocation...)
        }
        // advance the pointer
        nextLocation += numberOfItemsToRead * sizeUInt16

        // convert the read array into a string
        let resultString = String(utf16CodeUnits: utf16Array, count: utf16Array.count)
        print(resultString)
    }

    // read the number of countries
    _ = withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &dataReadBufferUInt64) {bufPtr in
        countryBorderLineData.copyBytes(to: bufPtr, from: nextLocation...)
    }
    // advance the pointer
    nextLocation += sizeUInt64

    // This line SOMETIMES crashes (see crash subset of crash report)
    let numberOfCountries = Int(dataReadBufferUInt64)

    //...

}
```

The implementation of `Swift.Data` has changed recently, so it might be causing some issues, but the possibility is not high (little more than *very unlikely*).

If your code runs in the multithreaded context, that may lead *SOMETIMES crashes*.

Anyway, when you show more context, I will check it and update my answer again.

---

**OLD ANSWER**

It depends on how your is organized (you should better show the spec of the NSDataAsset), but your code consumes `numberOfBytesToRead * sizeUInt16` bytes, with this loop:

```
       // loop to read all content
       for _ in 0 ..< numberOfBytesToRead {

            //...

            // advance the pointer
            nextLocation += Int(sizeUInt16)

            //...
        }
```

After this loop, `nextLocation` may be pointing some unknown position,
which may:
- be exceeding the valid range of your `countryBorderLineData`
- cause `Int(dataReadBufferUInt64)` to overflow
- ...

---

And looping through each UTF-16 code point is not an efficient way to read UTF-16 String.

I would re-write your code as:

```
let sizeUInt16 = MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size
let sizeUInt64 = MemoryLayout<UInt64>.size

if let countryBorderLineData = data {
    var nextLocation = 0

    // the read buffers, one for each expected data type
    var dataReadBufferUInt16: UInt16 = 0
    var dataReadBufferUInt64: UInt64 = 0

    // read the string with the entry comment
    // read the length of the string
    _ = withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &dataReadBufferUInt16) {bufPtr in
        countryBorderLineData.copyBytes(to: bufPtr, from: nextLocation...)
    }
    // advance the pointer
    nextLocation += sizeUInt16

    // take the number of bytes we should read
    let numberOfBytesToRead = Int(dataReadBufferUInt16)

    // check if this is not an empty string
    if numberOfBytesToRead > 0 {
        assert(numberOfBytesToRead.isMultiple(of: sizeUInt16))

        // target buffer of the string
        var utf16Array: [UInt16] = Array(repeating: 0, count: numberOfBytesToRead/sizeUInt16)

        utf16Array.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {bufPtr in
            countryBorderLineData.copyBytes(to: bufPtr, from: nextLocation...)
        }
        // advance the pointer
        nextLocation += numberOfBytesToRead

        // convert the read array into a string
        let resultString = String(utf16CodeUnits: utf16Array, count: utf16Array.count)
        print(resultString)
    }

    // read the number of countries
    _ = withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &dataReadBufferUInt64) {bufPtr in
        countryBorderLineData.copyBytes(to: bufPtr, from: nextLocation...)
    }
    // advance the pointer
    nextLocation += sizeUInt64

    // This line SOMETIMES crashes (see crash subset of crash report)
    let numberOfCountries = Int(dataReadBufferUInt64)
    //...

}
```

---

My guess might be wrong and the code above would not solve your issue, in such cases, please show more info about your data and I can correct my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond. I do not exactly understand why "nextLocation may be pointing some unknown position,"... did I miss something, or is "nextLocation" only incremented if a read happened? The optimized code is great, I will use it anyway ;-).... will update question with the data structure

Comment: @Hardy_Germany, for example, assume `numberOfBytesToRead == 4`, then your `for`-loop reads 8-bytes.

Comment: no not really, I reused a code here and the variable name is misleading, sorry for that. It should read "numberOfElementsToRead". The "number of bytes to read" is always a multiple of "sizeUInt16" which is MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size, which is 2

Comment: @Hardy_Germany, that sort of super-_misleading_ naming would prevent to solve your issue... Anyway, the crash report is showing that your app is accessing some memory space which is not allowed to access from an app. Usually such as `let numberOfCountries = Int(dataReadBufferUInt64)` would not cause this sort of issue, so other parts of your code is doing something wrong and you may need to find which part.

Comment: <sigh>, I will patch the code snippet... I also did not see any problem in that line of code, but it is explicitly shown (line x in file y). The rest of the methods is very similar to this snippet... Is it possible that swift/Foundation/IOS has a bug there ? maybe caused by my "robust" way of reading the String elements in a loop?

Comment: @Hardy_Germany, _similar_ is not enough. Please show exact code. Very unlikely it would be a bug of Swift or iOS. And "robust" is another misleading term, with using a loop, you may have more chance of including **bugs of your code**.

Comment: @Hardy_Germany, I may need to correct one thing. `Data` to `NSData` bridging sometimes shows buggy behavior, better avoid using `NSData` methods with `as NSData`.

Comment: Many thanks for that. I will try the code you suggested. I do not think it is a multithreaded issue, as all methods are called by a GCD serial queue. (I will add that to the question). To "similar": This method is quite simple. The different values are read by the same pattern you see in the code snippet (read one value, advance by size of dataType ...). There is no other logic etc... But I think the hint about the bridge between swift-data and NSData was very important. I will try this and publish an updated version to AppStore. If the crashes are gone, I will accept your answer.

Comment: sorry to bother you again. The statement        "utf16Array.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {bufPtr in
            countryBorderLineData.copyBytes(to: bufPtr, from: nextLocation...)
        }" 
caused a heap overflow. If I used the loop (reading one UInt16 per loop, using 
"   _ = withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &dataReadBufferUInt16) {bufPtr in
        countryBorderLineData.copyBytes(to: bufPtr, from: nextLocation...)
    }" 
everything works fine. Do you have an explanation for it? I like the idea of getting rid of the loop, but ...

Comment: @Hardy_Germany, Thanks for reporting. But the code is running fine with my simple testing data. If you can share a testing data, I will check it. By the way, serial queue may use other threads than the main queue, so there may be some multithreaded issue.

Comment: :–) I hope it is not on Main, as I want to run that methods in parallel to UI. At the time this method is called, the main interface is up and running. The content of the file is additional information which will bring to the UI as soon as it is ready. So main thread should be free for user interaction.

Comment: I think there might be a problem with stack/heap size. Yesterday one of the runs i did with address sanitizer crashed with „tried to allocate more that 7 mBytes“ on that „copyBytes“ statement. The variable „NumberOfItemsToRead“ was 65 at this moment ...would it be possible that the whole system is overloaded and stack and heap collides, just because it is too much nested etc.? The number of threads at this moment was quite low, just 4 or 5, but one of the crash reports I analysed, shows more than 40 threads and the crash was on thread 33. this might also explain the „Occasional“ characteristic

Comment: @Hardy_Germany, you need to assure that all the data structure updated by this method would never be accessed from the main thread until it is done. Any sort of simultaneous access (for example, the main thread may only read and never modifies them, that still can be a harmful simultaneous access) will cause every sort of unexpected result.

Comment: yes, you are right, main should not read until work is done, but I think that is ensured. The data is used in map overlays. And I override the draw() methode, so main will read the data during that.  But the overlays are activated AFTER that data is read into memory.

Comment: @Hardy_Germany, anyway I do not have the data you are using and I cannot  check if the overlays things really activated AFTER that is ready... Please provide verifiable data and code.

Comment: I will try to provide a set of data and code for you and put it on a github directory ... many thanks for the help, hints and comments so far this helps a lot!

Comment: AAHHHH... shame, shame, shame on me. When I put some additional comments to the code, to explain you the flow, I found my error. It is not assured that main is not reading it while data are still build up! I think that is the root cause.. it is sooo obvious ... shame, shame ... So many thanks for the comments, hints etc. and especially for the tip with NSData vs Data ....

Comment: @Hardy_Germany, thanks for reporting. I would be really happy if my answer helped improve your app.